# OpenJFX: (Gluon) SDK vs. Maven dependencies

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, openjfx

I am currently migrating a Java 8 code basis to Java 11. Since OpenJDK never contained JavaFX/OpenJFX I now need to handle JFX as an external dependency:

1. using Gluon's OpenJFX SDK
2. including OpenJFX as an external dependency via Maven Central

**Question 1**: Is there a substantial difference between the two approaches?

**Question 2**: Which approach would be the better one?

Comment: Given that both approaches use the _same_ artifacts, I'm not sure if the question is about the benefits of developing with or without build tools?

Comment: @JoséPereda Telling me that those are the same artifacts answer my question, thank you :-)